# Wordpress, text before variable if not empty

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php echo $yearbuilt = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'yearbuilt', true); if ( !empty($yearbuilt) ) ?>
```

I want the word "Built" before the custom field yearbuilt and only if yearbuilt is NOT empty. I've worked on this for hours and nothing I tried worked. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple

```
echo ((get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'yearbuilt', true) != '') ? 'Built ' . get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'yearbuilt', true) : '');
```

`get_post_meta` will return something, even if there is no post meta set, in your case an empty string (since 3rd argument is set to `true`), so `$yearbuilt` won't return `true` to an empty check.
Also, calling `get_post_meta` twice is not really inefficient, since it gets value from cache anyway.

Comment: Thank you!!!! That worked and I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @user2568633 You're welcome. Don't forget to accept an answer :)